# Append form input text to div on submit

Tags: javascript

At the moment I'm just trying to post their comment to the comment div, `commentsbox1`.

HTML:

```
 <form id="commentform" name="commentform" onsubmit="submitComment();">
    <input id="commenttext" type="text" placeholder="Leave a comment..." name="commenttext">
    <input type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px"> <!-- submit by pressing enter -->
 </form>
```

Javascript:

```
function submitComment(){
    var commenttext = $('#commenttext').val();
    $('#commentsbox1').append(commenttext);
};
```

Currently it seems to do nothing at all. It says the function is unused too.

Comment: when you submit the form the page will refresh, you know that, right?

Comment: That would cause the page to refresh. You have nothing canceling the submit event.

Comment: I'm going to submit it with javascript $.post

Comment: @frosty: it doesn't matter, whatever the way you are submitting the form, you're explicity calling that function on submit, therefore it will fire only when the form is submitted, which is translated into "the page will refresh and you won't see the expected result, or you will see it just for a few seconds if you're lucky enough".

Comment: The page isn't even refreshing though

Comment: No. Wait a second. Are you performing an ajax request or are you submitting the form? using $.post you perform an ajax request, hence you have to call the function once the request is complete.

Comment: I'm going to post the value of the input text box to a table, but I also want to append the text to a div to show them they commented.

Comment: and what is the process that perform the post? please share that part of the code, I'm pretty sure the problem is there.

Comment: I haven't made that yet, at the moment I'm just trying to post the value of the textbox on submit to the div (without refreshing the page)

Comment: $('#commentsbox1').append("text"); - this isn't even working inside document ready. http://puu.sh/hLzlc/5baf53f5bb.png - also it's using GET putting ?commenttext=text at the end of the URL

Comment: of course it doesn't, it is completely wrong. Remove the function from the document ready and call that INSIDE the document ready!

Comment: Huh? I'm really confused atm

Comment: You are confused because you don't know the basics of javascript, or perhaps you're not following a valid tutorial. In order to accomplish what you want to do, I would suggest you to follow this example instead, I rewrote it following your example : http://jsfiddle.net/8usn9s8s/ . Please parse the javascript code inside your $(0ducment).ready and you will be done, but I would recommend you to first understand the basics of javascript and then try to accomplish such things ;)

Comment: Why does jQuery code work outside of document ready? I thought all code had to go inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <form id="commentform" name="commentform" onsubmit="submitComment(event);">
```

and in the function:

```
    function submitComment(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         var commenttext = $('#commenttext').val();
         $('#commentsbox1').append(commenttext);
    };
```

This will prevent refresh of the page.

Comment: The page isn't even refreshing for some reason though.

Comment: I prefer ``e.preventDefault()`` over ``return false`` as it shows your intention better.

Comment: @frosty. If you don't cancel the event the page shud refresh. Can you show your problem in a fiddle then?

Comment: @frosty Add `event` inside `submitComment(event)` and just change the way the JavaScript block is loaded to no wrap (head) in fiddle. [Your Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fbyoLo5b/14/)

Comment: Seems to work now, but why does that function not go inside document ready? It seems that was the main issue.

Answer (score 1):

It works, but before you see the result, the page is refreshed.

```
function submitComment(){
    var commenttext = $('#commenttext').val();
    $('#commentsbox1').append(commenttext);

    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the form you should override the normal behaviour of the button:

```
$('#myBtn').on('click',function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    //do what you want to do
});
```

Comment: This doesn't address the issue.